# Services and translated nodes

Tags: nodes, i18n-l10n

I have a website where three languages are present. I am requesting nodes through the Services API endpoint and that part is working well.

When requesting a node via JSON, how does the API let me know the requested node ID is associated to translated nodes?

I know the translated nodes do contain a "tnid" record of the original node, but the original node doesn't have anything to indicate that there are translated nodes.

Answer (score 0):

To know if there are translations available for particular node, You need to call the below function to get the available translation nodes.

```
$translations = translation_node_get_translations($node->tnid);
```

Ref : [Function translation_node_get_translations](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!translation!translation.module/function/translation_node_get_translations/7.x)

So what you can do is, You can call this function when you are returning node from service API along with translated nodes.

Hope this will help.

Thanks

Comment: For a mobile app, I would need to somehow expose that function? Or is having the "tnid" enough. Something tells me it is possibly not enough for a mobile app?